# Get a constructor variable in promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, fetch-api

I can't get a constructor variable within my fetch call using javascript and react. I would like the value of this.state.numXLabels within the .then(function(json) callback, but I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined(…). What is the proper way of doing this? Here is the relevant code:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined(…)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class StockGraph extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { numXLabels: 0 }
     var url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/MSFT'+
           '.json?api_key=bCRpjzvgPNkxLzqAv2yY';
    fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(json) {
      console.log(this.state.numXLabels);
       //this.setState({
        // numXLabels: 30
       //})
    })
  }
...
```

Comment: Have a look at [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572) for the general problem, although there's probably a react-specific solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not try to use state or make ajax calls in the constructor of your React component. Instead, put that call inside one of the [lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods) that fires immediately, like `componentWillMount`. Also to access `this.state` inside of your ajax callback, you will need to bind `this` to the function. Using the [fat arrow function syntax](http://www.ian-thomas.net/autobinding-react-and-es6-classes/) is the most straightforward way.

```
class StockGraph extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { numXLabels: 0 }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        var url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/MSFT'+
           '.json?api_key=bCRpjzvgPNkxLzqAv2yY';
        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
           return response.json()
         })
        .then((json) => {
            console.log(this.state.numXLabels);
            //this.setState({
             // numXLabels: 30
           //})
        })
    }
    ...
```

Comment: thanks! the binding was the key. moving to componentWillMount is also nice for structural cleanliness. fat arrow syntax is a great tip. can also be achieved like :  .then(function(json){
            console.log(this.state.numXLabels);
        }.bind(this))